# How do you use input function along with def function?

Tags: python, function

I'm new to programming. I have a bit of problem with python coding (with def function).

So basically the code has to give the smaller number out of 2 numbers.

Question:
Write codes to perform the following tasks:

1. Define a function smaller_num that takes in two numbers to
   determine and return the smaller number of the two.
   Ask user for two numbers
   Use the function to determine the smaller number and display the result

So I had user input instead of calling the function and adding value inside the variable.

This is how my code looks like:

```
def smaller_num(x,y):
    if x>y:
        number= y
    else:
        number= x
    return number

smaller_num(x= input("Enter first number:-") ,y= input("Enter second number:-"))

print("The smaller number between " +  str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " is " + str(smaller_num))
```

How do I correct it? For now it's not working because "x" is not defined. But I feel that I defined them clearly both in def function and input function. So how do I fix this?

Thanks for those who respond to this question.

Comment: Please, format your code

Comment: I must commend you greatly for showing us what you tried instead of simply asking us how to solve your tasks. Well done :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You never actually defined `x` and `y` globally. You only defined it in the function when you did `def smaller_num(x, y)`.

When you do `smaller_num(x= input("Enter first number:-") ,y= input("Enter second number:-"))`
, you aren't creating variables called `x` and `y`, you are just creating parameters for your function.

In order to fix your code, create the variable `x` and `y` before you call your function:

```
def smaller_num(x, y): ## Can be rephrased to  def smaller_num(x, y):
    if x > y:          ##                          if x > y:
        number = y     ##                              return y
    else:              ##                          else:
        number = x     ##                              return x
return number

x = input("Enter first number:-")
y = input("Enter second number:-")
result = smaller_num(x, y)
print("The smaller number between " +  str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " is " + str(result))
```

The other reason your code is not working is because you're not assigning the returned value of the function back into a variable. When you `return` something from a function, and again when you call the function, you need to assign the value to a variable, like I have: `result = smaller_num(x, y)`.

When you called your function, you never assigned the value to a variable, so it has been wasted.

---

Also, are you using Python 3 or 2.7? In python 3 using `input()` will return a string, and to convert this to an integer, you can call `int()` around the `input()` function.

Comment: I'd really appreciate feedback as to know why my post was downvoted, thanks :)

Comment: That's not true, you can call and assign x and y as the `raw_input` in your parameters and it functions perfectly fine. The lack of storing the result is the only problem.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Unless I'm reading the code wrong, what I pointed out should be an error, since in the last line he says `str(x)`, which was never created globally. Same with `str(y)`

Comment: Oh, oops. I thought you meant that calling a function using `raw_input` as the parameter was a problem. I missed that line that called `x` and `y` again in the code.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Yep, you missed it in your answer too :P

Comment: As an improvement you could cast input as int(input()) and do the error handling.

Comment: @fsacer True, but it is unsure whether the user is using Python 3 or 2.7 (probably 3)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
def smaller_num(x,y):

    if x>y:
        number= y
    else:
        number= x
    return number


x = input("Enter first number:-")

y = input("Enter second number:-")

smaller = smaller_num(x,y)

print("The smaller number between " +  str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " is " + str(smaller))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
def smaller_num(x,y):
    if x>y:
        number = y
    else:
        number = x
    return number

x = input("Enter first number:-")
y = input("Enter second number:-")

print("The smaller number between " +  str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " is " + str(smaller_num(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
def smaller_num(x,y):
    if x>=y:
        number = y
    else:
        number = x
    return number

x = input("Enter first number:-")
y = input("Enter second number:-")
print("The smaller number between " +  str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " is " + str(smaller_num(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def smaller_num(x,y):
    if x>y:
        number= y
    else:
        number= x
    return number

k=smaller_num(x= input("Enter first number:-") ,y= input("Enter second number:-"))

print("The smaller number between x  & y  is ", k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def smaller_num():
    x=int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    y=int(input('Enter the second number: '))
    if x<y:
        return x
    else:
        return y
print('The smaller number is: ',smaller_num())
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could help us to understand what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem!